# Show a list of recently modified pages with date

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using the following which works great:

```
<?php
$today = current_time('mysql', 1);
$howMany = 10;
if ( $recentposts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, post_title FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'page' AND post_modified_gmt < '$today' ORDER BY post_modified_gmt DESC LIMIT $howMany")):
?>
<ul>
<?php
foreach ($recentposts as $post) {
if ($post->post_title == '') $post->post_title = sprintf(__('Post #%s'), $post->ID);
echo "<li><a href='".get_permalink($post->ID)."'>";
the_title();
echo '</a></li>';
}
?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But need to know how I can add the modified date at the closing `</li>` tag. I tried several methods using this page http://bit.ly/13zkdP8 but cannot seem to get it to work. Also, I saw this similar question: http://bit.ly/13zkEsP but I'm wanting to display pages and not posts. I'm learning PHP so please excuse my ignorance ;)

Comment: Why not selecting `post_modified_gmt` along with id & post_title in your query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get that info from the DB, then display it accordingly:

```
<?php 
$today = current_time('mysql', 1);
$howMany = 10;
if ( $recentposts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, post_title, post_modified_gmt FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'page' AND post_modified_gmt < '$today' ORDER BY post_modified_gmt DESC LIMIT $howMany")):
?>
<ul>
<?php
foreach ($recentposts as $post) {
    if ($post->post_title == '') 
        $post->post_title = sprintf(__('Post #%s'), $post->ID);
    echo "<li><a href='".get_permalink($post->ID)."'>";
    the_title();
    echo '</a> ' . mysql2date('d/m/Y', $post->post_modified_gmt) .'</li>';
}
?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the `post_modified_gmt` field to your select list:

`$wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, post_title, post_modified_gmt FROM...`

then you can retrieve it like you are would any other field:

`$post->post_modified_gmt`

and if you want to format it, you can use the php [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class or [MySQL's date formatting options](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html).